# Java - XMLGregorianCalendar Exception

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, gregorian-calendar

I am working on a web service program that makes calls back and forth in the form of XML. My issue is not with that however. When I run this locally (in Eclipse) on my machine, it seems to work. However, when my coworker runs it/if I attempt to run it on the server, he gets this exception before the web service is even called:

Exception #6 in ClientMain.java java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 2012-07-09T08:19:44-0400

Does anyone have any idea why it would take the argument on one machine but not the other? The build should not be the issue as I copied my entire eclipse workspace on a thumbdrive (so all associated jars and the build path should have carried over). As far as the server run, I exported the entire program as a runnable jar (running Eclipse Indigo) and get a similar issue.

I'd appreciate any insight!

Stacktrace/Output:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 2012-07-09T09:19:42-0400
      at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl$Parser.skip(Unknown Source)
      at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl$Parser.parse(Unknown Source)
      at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
      at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl.newXMLGregorianCalendar(Unknown Source)
      at com.travelport.worldspanimageserver.client.ClientMain.requestRun(ClientMain.java:231)******************************************************
Running by Yesterday's Date ...
2012-07-09T09:19:42-0400
Current date being used is 2012-07-09T09:19:42-0400
Exception #6 in ClientMain.java java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 2012-07-09T09:19:42-0400

      at com.travelport.worldspanimageserver.client.ClientMain.runTypeCheck(ClientMain.java:161)
      at com.travelport.worldspanimageserver.client.ClientMain.main(ClientMain.java:81)
Exception #13 in ClientMain.java java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Method causing exception:

```
    import java.text.DateFormat;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Calendar;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Properties;
    import java.util.TimeZone;

    import javax.mail.Message;
    import javax.mail.Session;
    import javax.mail.Transport;
    import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
    import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
    import javax.swing.text.Document;
    import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConfigurationException;
    import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory;
    import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;

    import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
    import org.joda.time.format.ISODateTimeFormat;

        public static void requestRun(String strRunType) throws DatatypeConfigurationException{
                //-TODO: determine how date is passed in/retrieved from database        
                 GregorianCalendar c = new GregorianCalendar();

                 XMLGregorianCalendar dateTime = null;

                 if (strRunType == "fullLoad") {dateTime = null;}
                 if (strRunType.substring(0,2).equals("OD")) 
                 { 
                     System.out.println("Current date being used is " + DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(strRunType.substring(2,strRunType.length())));
                     dateTime = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(strRunType.substring(2,strRunType.length()));
                 }
                 if (strRunType.substring(0,2).equals("DT")) 
                 { 
                     System.out.println("Current date being used is " + strRunType.substring(2,strRunType.length()));           
                     dateTime = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(strRunType.substring(2,strRunType.length()));
                 }

 String address = "http://vhligssas001:31860/services/ImageViewerService"; /**getServiceURL(sServer);**/

           try
           {
              ArrayList<PropertyType> propertyIdList = null;                                         
              ArrayList tempList = null;

               if (strRunType.equals("properties"))
               {
                  propertyIdList = getPropertiesFromFile(); //to fix later               
               }
               else
               {
                  propertyIdList = initialCall(dateTime, propertyIdList, address);
               }

               secondCall(propertyIdList, address);

           }  
           catch(Exception e)
           {
              System.out.println("Exception #5 in ClientMain.java " + e);
              try
              {
                 postMail("Exception #5 in ClientMain.java " + e);
              }
              catch (Exception e1)
              {
                  e1.printStackTrace();
              }
              System.exit(16);
           }  
       }  
       catch(Exception e)
       {
          System.out.println("Exception #6 in ClientMain.java " + e);
          try
          {
             postMail("Exception #6 in ClientMain.java " + e);
                 e.printStackTrace(); //added

          }
          catch (Exception e1)
          {
             e1.printStackTrace();
          }
          System.exit(16);
       }        
    }
```

Main Class:

```
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception 
        {
            String sRunType = new String("");
         try
            {    
              File fPropertiesToLoad = new File("runType.txt");
              BufferedReader in = null;
              String strRunType = new String("");

               if (!fPropertiesToLoad.exists())
               {         
                  System.out.println("******************************************************");
                  System.out.println("Exception #1 - Run Type file does not exist");
                  System.out.println("******************************************************");
                  postMail("Exception #1 - Run Type file does not exist");
                  System.exit(16);
               }           
               else
               {
                   in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("runType.txt"));   
                   if ((strRunType = in.readLine()) != null)
                   {
                       sRunType = strRunType.trim();
                   }
                   in.close();     
                   runTypeCheck(sRunType);
               }
            }        
            catch (Exception e)
            {
               System.out.println("Exception #2 in ClientMain.java " + e);
               postMail("Exception #2 in ClientMain.java " + e);
               System.exit(16);
            }
        }
```

runTypeCheck:

```
    public static void runTypeCheck(String sRunType)
        {
            try
            {
             //Hard-coded in "yesterday" as the date
             sRunType = "DT";

             System.out.println("******************************************************");
             DateTimeFormatter parser2 = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeNoMillis();

             if (sRunType.equals("DT")) 
             {
                 System.out.println("Running by Yesterday's Date ...");
                 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                 cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
                 DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
                 sRunType =  dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
                 System.out.println(sRunType);
                 sRunType = sRunType.replaceAll("-0500", "-05:00");
                 sRunType = "DT" + sRunType;
                 requestRun(sRunType);
             }
System.out.println("******************************************************");

       }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
           System.out.println("Exception #4 in ClientMain.java " + e);
           try
           {
              postMail("Exception #4 in ClientMain.java " + e);
           }
           catch (Exception e1)
           {
              e1.printStackTrace();
           }
           System.exit(16);
        }  
    }
```

only output:

```
******************************************************

Running by Yesterday's Date ...

2012-07-09T08:19:44-0400

Current date being used is 2012-07-09T08:19:44-0400

Exception #6 in ClientMain.java java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 2012-07-09T08:19:44-0400
```

Comment: Your exception is referencing `ClientMain.java` but you haven't supplied that code.

Comment: The output is misleading since there is no correlation between the code posted and the output.

Comment: I agree the string "Exception #6" doesn't appear anywhere. In any case a copy of the top of the stacktrace would be more useful

Comment: Sorry about that. I must have left out the bottom half of the method. N00b mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your 'date' that you get from `strRunType.substring(2,strRunType.length())` isn't a valid `lexicalRepresentation` of the date.

You'll need to get your input value correctly formatted in order to parse as an `XMLGregorianCalendar` object.

The error being that you are missing a `:` in the `-04:00` in your date.

Which you must have been aware of because of `sRunType = sRunType.replaceAll("-0500", "-05:00");` code... except you were using a 5 instead of a 4?